# Words for the long and short parts of the letter L

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the typographic or calligraphic term for the vertical stroke in the letter L, and for the horizontal part of the letter L?

Ascender doesn't describe the entire vertical line in this letter (as far as I know), and I'm clueless about the horizontal part.

Comment: What is wrong with "vertical" and "horizontal"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Stem* and *Arm*

[image: stem and arm of a letterform]

<sub>Source [Adobe Print Publishing Technical Guides — *Typography basics: Anatomy of letterforms*](https://www.infor.uva.es/%7Edescuder/docencia/IG/letterform_anatomy.pdf)</sub>

Comment: But in the letter L wouldn't it make more sense to call the horizontal extension a "foot"? (Not a criticism just me wondering out aloud)

Comment: According to Wikipedia the lower extension is called the [*horizontal bar*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface_anatomy) but then it says *"A longer horizontal stroke at the top or bottom, as in E T, is called an arm"*

Comment: @Mari-LouA - And then the serif is a toe? :-)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Here’s a visual showing the *E*’s lower horizontal as an arm: [Typedia](https://bit.ly/33Lcmq8)... From [TypeDecon](https://bit.ly/3qBkId4): *The top of the capital T and the horizontal strokes of the F and E are examples of arms... Sometimes arm is used interchangeably with bar or crossbar or cross stroke.* [**But**](https://bit.ly/3FDsCqF): *Although often used interchangeably, the bar differs from an arm and a cross stroke because each end connects to a stem or stroke and doesn’t (usually) intersect/cross over the stem or stroke.*